# How to put List Grup Items below the "Create Button"

Tags: bootstrap-4, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I have List Group Items as you can see from picture below inside dark card, "JavaScript 2.1" text there is, primary create button, I just want to, put List group items below, not in the same row with Button[image]
- My View

```
@extends('layouts.forum') 

@section('heading')
    <div class="d-block float-right">
        <a href="{{route('thread.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Create Thread</a>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('content')

    @include('pages.forums.thread.inc.thread-list')

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `float-right` from `<div class="d-block float-right">`

Comment: after it taking all width, I want to be small and content below